# How to handle "more than one instance of overloaded function"

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am writing a C++/cli wrapper library for a native codebase, but the native codebase has a conflict with a function of the same name in the Windows API: [ReleaseSemaphore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685071(v=vs.85).aspx). Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to not use the Windows API version?

Comment: The native codebase has this function in the global namespace? For shame

Comment: Easiest would be to change the name `ReleaseSemaphore` in the native codebase. There is not much else you can do.

Comment: @StoryTeller well, the native codebase is for an embedded system running an operating system that isn't windows. So, it makes sense, but is still a pita.

Comment: Not sure why this question deserved a downvote.

Comment: @E-rich First, you tag C and C++

Comment: If nothing else helps, you could perhaps do it with a #define ReleaseSemaphore ThisFunctionIsDisabled directly before including the windows headers, and directly after #undef ReleaseSemaphore. Dirty, but I can't imagine another way currently.